# Angular directives &scope issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with a pre-existing template trying to Angularize it.

I have 3 directives, which is basically a card, a card-header and card-body:

```
<card>
    <card-header title="My Card">
        <input type="text" ng-model="userSearch" />
    </card-header>
    <card-body>
        <card ng-repeat="item in object | filter:userSearch">
            <card-body>{{ item.name }}</card-body>
        </card>
    </card-body>
</card>
```

I'm sure you can see the issue... I can't get the filter to pick up the model due to scoping issues. Because I have my own html within the directives, I need to use the `transclude: true`, and from my understanding that creates its own scope.

Card:

```
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: false,
    template: '<div class="card" ng-transclude></div>',
}
```

Card Header:

```
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    requires: 'card',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: false,
    scope: {
        title: '@',
        secondary: '@',
        theme: '@'
    },
    template: '<div class="card-header" ng-class="theme"><h2 ng-if="title">{{ title }}<small>{{ secondary }}</small></h2><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
}
```

Card Body:

```
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    requires: '^card',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: false,
    scope: {
        padding: '@',
        theme: '@'
    },
    template: '<div class="card-body" ng-class="theme" ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
        if($scope.padding)
            angular.element($element[0]).addClass('card-padding');
    }
}
```

Seems like it should be a simple concept, but I've no idea how I can get around this when I have my own scope items, but need to transclude and have my own scope items.

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: Could having a controller on the Card work? The child directives have access to the parent directive controller: https://thinkster.io/egghead/directive-communication

Comment: Hmm I could do, but the issue is if I have card directives nested in each other, I imagine that could also cause issues? Shall have a play.

Comment: Why do you set `scope: false` then create isolated scopes? Are you sure what param will be taken into account exactly?

Comment: @top.dev Not sure, removing it has no effect - although I do understand what the issue is now, but can't think how to get get around it atm.

Comment: Create a plunkr - you'll have more chances of getting help

Answer (score 1):

First, I think maybe you have a markup issue.  Here is what I think you meant:

```
<card>
    <card-header title="My Card">
        <input type="text" ng-model="userSearch" />
    </card-header>
    <card-body>
        <card ng-repeat="item in object | filter:userSearch">
            <card-body>{{ item.name }}</card-body>
        </card>
    </card-body>  <!--this was card-header, which doesn't make sense -->
</card>
```

When you use ng-transclude inside of a directive, the content that is transcluded uses a ***new scope*** that is a ***sibling of the directive scope***.  So, if you were to analyze your scope tree, here is what you'd have (A is the parent scope of the entire block, () indicates an isolated scope):

```
<card A>
    <card-header A.B.(C)>   
        <input A.B.D ng-model="A.B.D.userSearch"> 
    </card-header>
    <card-body A.E.(F)>
        <card A.E.G.H ng-repeat="A.E.G.H.item in A.E.G.object | filter: A.E.G.userSearch">
             <card-body A.E.I.(J)>{{A.E.I.K.item.name}}
        </card>
    </card-body>
</card>
```

Note a few things (besides the obvious "that's a lot of scopes!):

A.B.D.userSearch is an entirely different property than A.E.G.userSearch.  A.E.G does not prototypically inherit from A.B.D.  This is why the filter doesn't work.

Also note that A.E.G.H.item is also a different property that A.E.I.K.item - this won't work either.

How to fix:

The easiest way to fix is to not use ng-transclude, but use manual transclusion and take control of the scope used by the transcluded content.

For example, the card transclusion would change to:

```
template: '<div class="card" transclude-target></div>'
link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
    transclude(scope, function(clone, scope){
         element.find('[transclude-target]').append(clone);
    }
}
```

> Aside:  ng-transclude essentially does:
>
> ```
> link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
>     transclude(scope.$parent.$new(), function(clone, scope){
>          element.find('[ng-transclude]').append(clone);
>     }
> }
> ```

What this does is make the transclusion use the directive scope rather than a sibling of the directive scope (or even a new scope)

The scope tree becomes:

```
<card A>
    <card-header A.(B)>   
        <input A.(B) ng-model="A.(B).userSearch"> 
    </card-header>
    <card-body A.(C)>
        <card A.(C) ng-repeat="A.(C).D.item in A.(C).object | filter: A.(C).userSearch">
              <card-body A.(C).D>{{A.(C).D.item.name}}</card-body>
        </card>
    </card-body>
</card>
```

Still not quite right (the isolated directives are breaking the inheritance chain we need).

Changing the other two directives (card-header and card-body) to use scope.$parent:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
    transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone, scope){
         element.find('[transclude-target]').append(clone);
    }
}
```

Yield's the following scope tree (now your filter will work {{item.name}} should display the correct version)

```
<card A>
    <card-header A.(B)>   
        <input A ng-model="A.userSearch"> 
    </card-header>
    <card-body A.(C)>
        <card A.E ng-repeat="A.E.item in A.object | filter: A.userSearch">
             <card-body A.E.(D)>{{A.E.item.name}}
        </card>
    </card-body>
</card>
```

I'm sure I've made a mistake in this somewhere, but I think it should explain what's going on.  I wish my explanation were simpler, but it's the best I can do.

Comment: Woah thanks. I totally get what you're going for and I now have it working... more or less. The `element.find` part didn't work, but replacing it with `angular.element(element[0]).append(clone);` does. Obviously this doesn't target the `transclude-target` bit but I still can't figure out how to target it. So right now it just appends it into the inner-most element.

Comment: My fault.  angular.element.find() doesn't support selectors.  I usually have jQuery installed along with angular.   jqLite.find does support tag names, so try changing the markup to <transclude-target></transclude-target> and using find('transclude-target').

Comment: Ah nice one :) Another thing, if I try adding a scope to `ma-card` (`<ma-card size="small"></ma-card>`), it doesn't load the inner `ma-card` directive. If it's a whole different issue, don't worry ha.

Comment: When you say "add scope", does that mean you set scope:true or use an isolated scope (scope: {})?

Comment: Isolated, not sure how else I'd apply the "size" into the class (`<div class="card" ng-class="size">`), with `scope: { size: '@' }`.

Comment: Ah, managed to get around it using links attr.size, apply it to the scope and I'm sorted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of your problem:

If inspecting your last directive, what I see is no model defined in the template.

Now when you specify template, it replaces the html inside the directive element, so that being the reason of your model not appearing.

That being said, you will have to include model inside your template if **item.name** is in  **card-body** directive.

Now when you use ng-transclude, it puts the original html back, that is why you are able to somewhat solve the problem(but scope causing the issue).

You will have to change the template as follows and will have to include item also in the isolated scope definition.

```
template: '<div class="card-body" ng-class="theme">{{item.name}}</div>'
```

If you don't want to modify it and want to use ng-transclude, there are two ways to call parent scope variables from child scope,

1. Use properties of a scope object instead.

So instead of having
    itmes as $scope.items you can instead use an object and have items
    as property: `$scope.itemModel.items`

Now if you modify these, they
    will reflect in parent scope as well. And its faster due to nature
    of javascript.

2. Not recommended but you can always call parent scope variables using
   $parent  both in view and controller.

Check if these works for you.